# Calling multiple Directmethod in a function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ext.net

I am building a web application using Ext.Net. I run into a problem today that I suddenly cannot call multiple server-side .NET Methods (DirectMethod) in a function.

For instance:

```
<script>
        function test1() {
            App.direct.Method1({ failure: function (msg) { Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', msg); } });
            App.direct.Method2({ failure: function (msg) { Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', msg); } });
        }        
</script>
```

This will only call Method2 but not both of them. Can someone help me, please? Many thanks.

Comment: both methods look identical to one and other. Maybe the issue resides in the fact that they both use the same instance to fire up an alert. Have you tried using two different methods that produce entirely different outcomes?

Comment: Thanks for your though. The methods do very different things, and they used to be OK. So I cannot imagine why suddenly they stop functioning as they should...Interestingly, it works fine on another computer, so I reset my computer and everything but did not help.

Comment: I just noticed now that if the app is opened with Internet Explorer (instead of Chrome), then it works fine. Any idea why it is the case ??

Comment: Could you chain these methods by calling `Method2` inside the `success` callback config of `Method1`? If `Method1` returns successfully, then call `Method2`.